# A compilation error has occurred / 'ClientIDMode' is not a member

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Getting a very strange error in the Event Log while trying the access a precompiled asp.net page. The error is Event Code 3007, "A compilation error has occurred. Further information reveals that it's tripping on the ClientIDMode property of the page, which is set to Static.

I have several other pages that use this same ClientIDMode=Static property with no problems. Also this compiles and runs just fine in a development environment. It's only when I move it to another server that the problem crops up.

What could it be?

Comment: Can you check that, on the server causing the problem, the App Pool is running under .NET 4 and not 2 ? ClientIDMode is not supported before v4

Comment: I did check that, but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why this error was occurring, but I was able to work around it by unchecking the "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable" option when publishing.

Comment: This is worth a look, it describes the differences between setting or not setting that option - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975787/what-is-the-difference-between-allowing-a-precompiled-visual-studio-web-page-to